# Замена регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как составить выражение следующего вида:

```
text.replace(new RegExp('< здесь может быть один или несколько пробелов или ни одного' + vars + 'здесь может быть один или несколько пробелов или ни одного, а здесь может быть какое то содержимое или ничего, здесь может быть один или несколько пробелов или ни одного, ну а здесь всё что угодно кроме / или нечего, сдесь тоже может быть один или несколько пробелов или нечего>', 'gim'), '<br $3 />');
```

Например, пробовал так:

```
var vars = "br";

text.replace(new RegExp('<[\s+]?' + vars + '[\s+]?([^<]*)?[\s+]?[^\/][\s+]?>', 'gim'), '<hr $3 />');
```

Не получилось. Вот примерно какие строки должны меняться:

```
< br class="hr" > на <hr class="hr" />
<   br   class="hr"   > на <hr class="hr" />
<   br     > на <hr />
<br > на <hr />
<br> на <hr />
```

и прочие варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = '<br>';
var pat = /<\s*(\S+)\s*([^>]*)>/gi;
str.replace(pat, '<$1 $2 />').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Вместо `(\S+)` и `$1` можете написать `br` и `hr` соответственно - будет ваш вариант.

Comment: я конешн уже сам сделал)))) но ваш вариант тоже работает))))

Answer (score 0):

Говорят регулярку можно написать совершенно любую, но тут может быть проще сделать разбиением задачи на части.

К примеру сначала убрать пробелы после открывающего тега "`<`". Как то так, например:

```
text.replace(new RegExp(/<\s+/gim,'<');
```

Далее избавиться от пробелов в конце тега "`>`" и заменить его соответственно на "/>"

```
text.replace(new RegExp(/\s+>/gim,' />');
```

Теперь можно удалить лишние пробелы в внутри

```
text.replace(new RegExp(/\s+/gim,' ');
```

Ну и заменить собственно любое словосочетание на необходимое

```
var patt = "br";
var rep = "hr"

text.replace(new RegExp(patt, 'gim'), rep);
```

Так же можно обернуть это все в функцию для удобства. Сам не тестировал, но направление мысли думаю понятно.

В добавок могу посоветовать вот этот ресурс http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ , где "на живую" можно поиграться с регулярками. Я, бывает, использую этот сервис для работы с текстом, потому как редакторы редко предоставляют необходимый поиск/замену. А писать утилиты долго.